# How to use hasAndBelongsToMany models with foreign key in Loopback

Tags: loopbackjs

I have Customer and Group model:

Each customer may belong to multiple groups, while each group may have multiple customers.

I want to build a relation between them.

I added a `hasAndBelongsToMany` to both model. My goal is when using the API, I will be able to include all the groups that customers belong to if I send a url like this: `/api/Customers`,

and it will return `[{name: xxx, groups: ['northeast','northwest']},{name: xxx, groups: ['northeast']}]`.

How to configure something like this in the `model.json`?

```js
// Customer Model
{
  "name": "Customer",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
    "groupId": {
      "type": "array" // not sure what to do.
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "groups": {
      "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
      "model": "Group",
      "foreignKey": "customerId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}

// Group Model
{
  "name": "Group",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "label": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "customers": {
      "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
      "model": "Customer",
      "foreignKey": "groupId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to add something to model definitions.

Just in API calls add `include` like : `/api/Customers?filter[include]=groups`

And below is not necessary, you can remove it from model definition:

```
"groupId": {
      "type": "array" // not sure what to do.
    }
```